# How to use FreeFontType with libgdx Skin and AssetManager

Tags: libgdx

Till now from all the reading I have done I am sure I can't put freefonttype directly into uiskin.json like Bitmap fonts and I have to add them to the skin programatically in runtime.

Tried to follow this solution but I get uiskin.json not loaded error as I am trying to access Skin using AssetManager.
http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=10152

```
public void loadSkins() {
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/font.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 32;
    BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
    generator.dispose();
    Skin skin = new Skin();
    skin.add("myfont", font12, BitmapFont.class);
    skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
}
```

This code is in my AssetManager class and all the assets gets loaded except uiskin.json

If I replace the whole code in loadSkins with below code then it gets loaded.

```
manager.load("data/uiskin.json", Skin.class);
```

Now if I try to access my Skin class the application crashes with asset uiskin.json not loaded error. Here is how I access the Skin class

```
manager.get("data/uiskin.json");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is, because you need to load the skin with the asset manager, not just the skin. There is an extra loader in the asset manager called SkinLoader. If you give it the Texture Atlas, it should load you your skin.

> Note: I am loading the font seperately from the skin. And add it later. If you want to reference the font in your .json file, you need to call Assetmanager.finishLoading() before trying to load the skin and add another parameter to your SkinLoader: **ObjectMap<String, Object>** add the font to it with **objectMap.put()** and add it to the SkinLoader with
>   **new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("skins/uiskin.atlas", *objectMap*)**

```
    // Queue font
    FileHandleResolver resolver = new InternalFileHandleResolver();
    app.assetManager.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator.class, new FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver));
    app.assetManager.setLoader(BitmapFont.class, ".ttf", new FreetypeFontLoader(resolver));
    FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter params = new FreetypeFontLoader.FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
    params.fontFileName = "font/stay_writer.ttf";
    params.fontParameters.size = 30;
    app.assetManager.load("stay_writer_30.ttf", BitmapFont.class, params);
    // Queue Skin
    app.assetManager.load("skins/uiskin.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    app.assetManager.load("skins/uiskin.json", Skin.class, new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("skins/uiskin.atlas"));
```

Later add the font to the skin:

`skin.add("default-font", app.assetManager.get("stay_writer_30.ttf", BitmapFont.class));`

Where "default-font" is the name of the font in the .json file and "stay_writer_30.ttf" is the name of the freetypefont.